# Are Frege and extended Frege systems separated conclusively?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computational-complexity, proof-theory

Buss in *Propositional Proofs in Frege and Extended Frege Systems* and *Short Proofs of the Kneser-Lovasz Coloring Principle* shows that propositional translations of Kneser-Lovasz Coloring Principle and truncated Tucker Lemma have extended Frege proofs with polynomial number of symbols and Frege proofs with only a quasi-polynomial number of symbols.

The first question is thus as follows.

> Do these results rule out the possibility that a polynomial sized Frege proof exist or are quasi-polynomial proof sizes only an upper bound?

In the same papers (and earlier in *Are there hard examples for
Frege systems?*) it is mentioned that Frege systems polynomially simulate extended Frege iff there are Frege proofs of $Con_{e\mathcal{F}}(n)$ formulas of polynomial size w.r.t. $n$.

The second question is, hence, as follows.

> Have there been any attempts to assess the size of Frege proofs of $Con_{e\mathcal{F}}(n)$?